# Python3 ginput warning : Using default event loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

The warning came about when I implemented the ginput part of the code.

```py
def twoClicks(color_img):
    from pylab import ginput, rcParams, imshow, draw, title, axis, close
    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 8

    imshow(color_img, interpolation='nearest', aspect='equal')
    title("Click the image twice")
    axis('off')
    user_input = ginput(2)
    draw()
    close()
    print(user_input)

    return
```

Executing the above code is giving me:

> /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2407:       MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI     is implemented
>       warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)

I would like to know what I am doing that is generating the warning and how to go about doing this the right way.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am in linux and the matplotlib output is being handled by the default interface (maybe GTK).

Comment: don't worry about that warning unless something else is also going wrong.

Comment: any good ideas on how to suppress it? Right now, users need to use the command line for some input and it looks bad when that warning pops up. I tried adding the line:
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)) without any success

Answer (score 2):

Check out the python tutorial of how to suppressing warnings, http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, in this case, use:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",".*GUI is implemented.*")
```

this applies a pattern to be looked for in the warning, meaning that other warnings will still be reported.